# Reflection over Type Constraints

Tags: c#, types, constraints

In class and method definitions, it's possible to add type constraints like `where T : IFoo`.

Is it possible to reflect over those constraints with `System.Type` or `MethodInfo`? I haven't found anything so far; any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can iterate through the generic parameters to the type, and for each parameter, you can ask for the constraint types.

You do this using:

- [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) of [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) to find the generic arguments to the type, ie. `Type<T>`, you would find `T`.
- [Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints.aspx) gives you the base types that each such parameter is constrained against, you call this on the arguments you find from the above method.

Take a look at this code, which you can run through [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/):

```
void Main()
{
    Type type = typeof(TestClass<>);
    foreach (var parm in type.GetGenericArguments())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(parm.Name);
        parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints().Dump();
    }
}

public class TestClass<T>
    where T : Stream
{
}
```

The output is:

```
T

Type [] (1 item)  
typeof (Stream)
```

To find other constraints, such as `new()`, you can use the `.GenericParameterAttributes` flags enum, example:

```
void Main()
{
    Type type = typeof(TestClass<>);
    foreach (var parm in type.GetGenericArguments())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(parm.Name);
        parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints().Dump();
        parm.GenericParameterAttributes.Dump();
    }
}

public class TestClass<T>
    where T : new()
{
}
```

Which outputs:

```
T

Type [] (1 item)  
typeof (Stream)

DefaultConstructorConstraint
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [GetGenericParameterConstraints()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints.aspx) method to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Using a previously found `System.Type` you can use `GetGenericParameterConstraints()`.

Here's an excellent MSDN article on [Generics and Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Lasse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432864) points out the relevant `Type` methods.  I used it as a reference while creating this extension method:

```
public static IList<Tuple<Type, Type[], GenericParameterAttributes>> GetTypeConstraints( this Type type )
{
    return type.GetGenericArguments()
        .Select( t => Tuple.Create( t, t.GetGenericParameterConstraints(), t.GenericParameterAttributes ) )
        .Where( t => t.Item2.Length > 0 || t.Item3 > GenericParameterAttributes.None )
        .ToList();
}
```

Interestingly, it seems that the `Type.BaseType` property on a generic parameter also returns a single type constraint.